# Add syntax highlighing to nbconvert raw cells in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, pygments

In Jupyter, I'd like to add syntax highlighting to Raw NBConvert cells (based on type). I'm looking for either (a) an existing plugin that accomplishes this or (b) some direction on writing a plugin to accomplish this.